# How can I make dolphin-emu's cmake scripts succeed?

Tags: cmake

I'm attempting to build dolphin-emu (https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-emu), and I get the following error while running cmake according to the instructions at http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-emu/wiki/Linux_Build.

I don't know much about cmake, and basic googling has not found a solution.

I'm running Linux Mint 12.

```
$ git clone https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-emu/ dolphin-emu
(...)
$ cd dolphin-emu
dolphin-emu$ mkdir Build
dolphin-emu$ cd Build
dolphin-emu/Build$ cmake ..
x86_64
OpenMP parallelization enabled
ALSA found, enabling ALSA sound backend
ao found, enabling ao sound backend
bluez found, enabling bluetooth support
PulseAudio found, enabling PulseAudio sound backend
-- Could NOT find OpenAL (missing:  OPENAL_LIBRARY OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
OpenAL NOT found, disabling OpenAL sound backend
-- checking for modules 'wayland-egl;wayland-client;wayland-cursor'
--   package 'wayland-egl' not found
--   package 'wayland-client' not found
--   package 'wayland-cursor' not found
Wayland support disabled
X11 support enabled
Xrandr found
-- checking for module 'xi>=1.5.0'
--   package 'xi>=1.5.0' not found
libav found, enabling AVI frame dumps
PortAudio not found, disabling mic support
Using static lzo from Externals
-- Could NOT find SDL2 (missing:  SDL2_LIBRARY SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Using shared SDL
-- checking for module 'libusb-1.0'
--   package 'libusb-1.0' not found
-- libusb-1.0 not found.
Could NOT find SFML (missing:  SFML_INCLUDE_DIR)
Using static SFML 1.5 from Externals
-- Could not find miniupnp
Using static miniupnpc from Externals
-- Could not find polarssl
Using PolarSSL from Externals
Using static SOIL from Externals
Using shared zlib
-- checking for one of the modules 'glew>=1.8'
Using static GLEW from Externals
-- Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing:  wxWidgets_FOUND) 
-- Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing:  wxWidgets_FOUND) 
Using static wxWidgets from Externals
gthread-2.0 found
pangocairo found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindGettext.cmake:83 (ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "translations" because another
  target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom
  target created in source directory
  "/home/jasmuth/Downloads/dolphin-emu/Source/Core/DolphinWX".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Source/Core/DolphinWX/CMakeLists.txt:181 (GETTEXT_CREATE_TRANSLATIONS)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: What is your CMake version?

Comment: Upgrading my version of cmake solved the issue. The apt-get version was out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading cmake from 2.8.7 (what comes with apt-get) to 2.8.12 (what is available via source install) fixed the issue.